# react-big- calendar Table TD overlapping outside Table and TD

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using react-big-calendar inside a table with tbody, tr, and td. When there is data in the calendar month, the react-big-calendar fits on the page and inside the panel. However, as I added events to the calendar, it overlaps over the table, tr, panel. The right side expands and I have to use the horizontal scrollbar to see the far right side.

I also tried the following and it helps make the calendar fit but it is hardcoding the width and I like the calendar to resize with the browser width.

style({height: "100vh", width: "100vh"})

width;"100%" does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I need it to stay fitted inside the table.

```
<table className={myStyle.myTableStyle}>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td width=98% className={myStyle.myPanel}>
      <Calendar 
        className="myCalendar"
        selectable={true}
        localizer={myLocalizer}
        defaultView="month"
        events={myEvents}
        style({height: "100vh"})
        popup={true}
      />
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to update your question to include the CSS so someone else can replicate it. Also what is `<td=98%` ?

Comment: ps: The message you deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306858/react-javascript-button-property-aria-label-result-in-parsing-error-invalid-left  try -> `props["aria-label"] =`..   Hopefully you never deleted because of that spammer..

Answer (score 0):

added to table styling in css

.tableStyle
  table-layout: fixed
  width: 100%

This prevents the table from running off the page